# Apache Spark 2.4 Structure Streaming read from Kafka always Binary structure after applied multiple transformations

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am working with Apache Spark 2.4 and I am reading the json data from kafka after applying multiple transformation on streaming query the final output is still binary.

```
val streamingDF = sparkSession.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("subscribe", "test")
      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
      .option("failOnDataLoss", value = false)
      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 50000L)
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka_server")
      .option("enable.auto.commit" , "false")
      .load()

val dataSet = streamingDF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String] 
val stream = dataSet.map{value => convertJSONToCaseClass(value)}
.map{data => futherconvertions(data)}.writeStream.format("console")
.outputMode(OutputMode.Update()).start()
```

After this I am getting the output like this on console.

```
Batch: 8
-------------------------------------------
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[01 00 63 6F 6D 2...|
|[01 00 63 6F 6D 2...|
|[01 00 63 6F 6D 2...|
```

Expected output suppose to be data-frame with multiple columns

Is there something I am doing wrong. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you simply `select($"value" cast "string")` and `.writeStream.format("console")
.outputMode(OutputMode.Update()).start()` afterwards (leaving your transformations aside)? We'd focus on just this cast alone.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski without any transformation other than cast it works pretty good but when i apply any transformation then there is a issue

Comment: Then you have nothing more left than to keep adding the remaining `map`s one by one and use `console` sink to verify the output. `map`s look suspicious and I'd recommend `withColumn` and standard functions instead. They'd give you a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to set "enable.auto.commit" as per docs.please refer kafka specific configurations
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

To convert the JSON to multiple columns, use `from_json`, as below:

```scala
val streamingDF = sparkSession.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("subscribe", "test")
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", value = false)
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 50000L)
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka_server")
  .load()
val df = streamingDF.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING)")         
                                                                 
 val mySchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("X", StringType, true),
  StructField("Y", StringType, true),
  StructField("Z", StringType, true))                            
                                                                 
val Resultdf = df.select(from_json($"value", mySchema).as("data")).select("data.*")
```